# Plugin for WP for parse TXT file (comma separated values) and import them into WP database

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my first time writing a simple plugin for Wordpress so don't be evil with me. See this is what I'm trying to do with my plugin:

1. Allow users from Admin CP to upload (temporary or not) a `.txt` file which contains several lines, each lines has some values as for example: `GALUE,YOMAR,A,PP 36199230,,MVD,Y,9992200030748,1,3B,3,Y,C`
2. I need to parse this data and then attach to existent user by matching their names with the ones extracted from uploaded data

By `attach to existent user` I mean create extra meta data for that users and persist to the DB. Also if it's possible I would like to add support to edit some of this metadata only.

That's all but I don't know how to start writing a plugin, I read the docs at WP site but isn't clear at all to me. Can any give me some tips or maybe a piece of code as starting point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to read the documentation, a lot. It starts with a simple header to a PHP file:

> ### [Standard Plugin Information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Standard_Plugin_Information)
>
> *The top of your Plugin's main PHP file must contain a standard Plugin information header. This header lets WordPress recognize that your Plugin exists, add it to the Plugin management screen so it can be activated, load it, and run its functions; without the header, your Plugin will never be activated and will never run. Here is the header format:*
>
> ```
>    <?php
>     /**
>      * Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin
>      * Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
>      * Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
>      * Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
>      * Author: Name Of The Plugin Author
>      * Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
>      * License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
>      */
> ```

Then, you'll have to create the plugin's UI with [**`add_(sub)menu_page()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) and auxiliary functions and [hooks](http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/).

To import the file, the basic is:

```
$import_file = $_FILES['import_file']['tmp_name'];
$csv = file_get_contents( $import_file );
```

That's from the tutorial [Building a settings import and export feature](http://pippinsplugins.com/building-settings-import-export-feature/), although it deals with JSON.

Also, you can learn from existing plugins, like [CSV Importer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/csv-importer/screenshots/), and researching the [`<plugin-development>` tag at WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development?sort=frequent&pageSize=50).

Comment: I've answered to this *"but I don't know how to start writing a plugin"*.